# What's the cheapest way to get from the Sunshine Coast to the Gold Coast without a car, other than hitchhiking?

Tags: australia, transportation, queensland, sunshine-coast, gold-coast

Normally I actually do hitchhike between these two (-:

But next time I can't leave until the 14th and have a flight out of the Gold Coast on the morning of the 16th. Hitching is not guaranteed to get me there in time if the weather or luck is unfavourable.

I'm guessing it's possible via one or more combinations of two buses, changing at Brisbane, but I have no idea which companies or if some other way might be superior.

If it makes any difference I'm leaving from Mooloolaba and going to either Mudgeeraba or Coolangatta.

Comment: Check out https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Mooloolaba/Gold-Coast-Airport-OOL for some train and bus options

Comment: Does anybody know why @traktor53 deleted their answer? I'm guessing it's something to do with Mooloolaba Station being a busstop. My dad lives up here and always gripes how confusing it is to call busstops stations, even though he never uses buses. Getting from Mudgeeraba to the airport is not a problem as I would stay with a friend there who has offered to take me to the airport, but I allowed that some way that drops me off at the airport might work out better anyway.

Comment: Are there any ground transportation search engines for Australia?

Comment: @hippietrail I deleted the answer temporarily because I mistook **Mooloolah** for **Mooloolaba**. I've corrected the answer and undeleted it.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm the only one I knew of is directions in Google Maps. Hilmar's comment shows another. I found Google frustratingly difficult to use. My answer started with already knowing Brisbane was serviced by country rail links and looking them up - my brother lives in a town serviced by the Caboulture line :-)

Comment: @traktor53: Ah yes I saw that eventually but after my Wi-Fi went bad when I wanted to add that to my comment (-:

Answer (score 4):

You can start by catching a [615 bus](http://www.railmaps.com.au/routedetails.php?RouteSelect=842&Board=1704&Alight=831) from **Mooloolaba** to to **Landsborough** that takes about 30 minutes.

Queensland rail have a station at **Landsborough** on the [Sunshine Coast Line](https://www.queenslandrail.com.au/Customers/Stations%20and%20Maps/Pages/SunshineCoastline.aspx) that runs into Brisbane with final stops at Bowen Hills, Fortitude Valley, Brisbane Central and Roma Street.

The [Gold Coast line](https://www.queenslandrail.com.au/Customers/Stations%20and%20Maps/Pages/GoldCoastline.aspx) starts at Bowen Hills, also with stops at Fortitude Valley, Brisbane Central and Roma Street,  and then onto Varsity Lakes, the stop in **Mudgeeraba**.

I assume you will be over-nighting on the Gold coast. Googling "How to get from Mudgeeraba to the gold coast airport" lists a variety of options. A shuttle service is probably the most expensive but may be the most reliable for an early morning flight.

*Update:*
[Bus route 760](http://www.railmaps.com.au/routedetails.php?RouteSelect=284&tstyle=) runs from Robina (the Gold Coast Line stop before Varsity lakes) and can take you on to **Coolangatta** in around 45 minutes (one of your options). The stop before Coolangatta is the airport!

A quick estimate put the cost of Mooloolaba to Coolangatta transport at around  AUD$50 or so. If you already have a go card (plastic transport card) and don't need a paper ticket it may be even cheaper.